# Quicker way to update all rows in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops

Is there a more efficient way to write this code? Or with less code?

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp 
FROM testtemplate

Declare @id INT
Declare @name VARCHAR(127)

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Temp) > 0 
BEGIN 

    SELECT TOP 1 @id = testtemplateid FROM #Temp
    SELECT TOP 1 @name = name FROM #Temp

    UPDATE testtemplate
    SET testtemplate.vendortestcode = (SELECT test_code FROM test_code_lookup WHERE test_name = @name)
    WHERE testtemplateid = @id

     --finish processing 
    DELETE #Temp Where testtemplateid = @id
END
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql for a pointer on how to do this, although Joe is correct (+1) (and much faster at typing than I was!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this in a single UPDATE with no need to loop.

```
UPDATE tt
    SET vendortestcode = tcl.test_code
    FROM testtemplate tt
        INNER JOIN test_code_lookup tcl
            ON tt.name = tcl.test_name
```

Comment: wow, I should have thought of that.  I didn't know you could join tables that don't actually have constraints (related keys) with one another.  This is way cool, and very powerful!

Comment: I know this is over 10 years old, but could anyone point a resource that explains in more detail what happens under the hood in this solution? I find it to be very elegant and would like to understand it better.

Comment: @EngelsLeonhardt  
[here is good article](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-sql-server-update-join)

Answer (score 7):

You could try a single update like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.vendortestcode = B.test_code
FROM testtemplate A
INNER JOIN test_code_lookup B
ON A.name = B.test_name
```

Also, the way you are doing it now is **wrong**, since you are taking a TOP 1 Id and a TOP 1 name in two separate querys, without an `ORDER BY`, so its not sure that you are taking the right name for your ID.

Comment: +1 for the comment on ordering!   This is one of the most dangerous fallacious assumptions people have about SQL.

Comment: @JNK - Yeah, of all the things that could be improved of that code, I think that the lack of an `ORDER BY` on those two queries is the most urgent one.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to update vendortestcode. Then your code reduces to one SQL statement:

```
update testtemplate set vendortestcode = dbo.get_test_code_from_name(name)
```